# Removing "\" in json object string

Tags: java, android

How can i remove special character "\" in the string below:

```
String x = {
    "message": {
        "@content": "toom"
    },
    "recipients": "[{\"@id\":\"1000001865\"}]",
    "room": {
        "@subject": "room"
    }
}
```

I used x.replaceAll("\\","") but it does not work.

Comment: That code won't compile. Don't mix Java and text.

Comment: technically x is not a String in your example. Why exactly doesn't `replaceAll("\\","")` work? any exceptions?

Comment: You don't want to do that.  Instead, parse the nested string as more JSON.

Comment: @GameDroids: No; it's a syntax error.  And that (a) won't work (regex) and (b) is wrong anyway (JSON parser)

Comment: Can i know the Purpose behind doing this ? May be we can provide a better way to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 6):

You must escape the backslash in the regex.

try

```
x.replaceAll("\\\\", "")
```

see [JavaRegularExpressions: 3.6. Backslashes in Java](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regex_backslashes)