# Getting an unespected extra escape character on Java Restful API JSON result string

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, jersey

I am creating a restful api(service) using maven and jersey. My Repository attributeMasterRepository retuns the data in String format.

```
JSONObject attribute = new JSONObject();

    attribute.put("Product_Brand", attributeMasterRepository.getProductBrand(cluster, CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan));
    attribute.put("Product_Type", attributeMasterRepository.getProductType(cluster, CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan));

   String attributeStr = "[" + attribute.toString() + "]";      
   return attributeStr;
```

My above code in the Service layer returns an unexpected "\" on the string.
I need to get rid of the "\".

Here is my Output:

```
{
 "Product_Type":
"[{\"active\":true,\"description\":\"ALL IN ONES\",\"id\":2},     
  {\"active\":true,\"description\":\"ACCESSORIES\",\"id\":1}]",
 "Product_Brand":
"[{\"active\":false,\"brand\":\"101 DALMATIANS\",\"id\":1}]"
}
```

Could you please let me know on how to get the "\" removed.

Thanks,
IRK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONObject.toString: how NOT to escape slashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563579/jsonobject-tostring-how-not-to-escape-slashes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not state which libraries you use, but also you can just replace the `\` characters:

```
json.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Similar questions:

- [Removing "\" in json object string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568681/removing-in-json-object-string)
- [JSONObject.toString: how NOT to escape slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563579/jsonobject-tostring-how-not-to-escape-slashes)