# JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have a JSON object as below. When I try to fetch the value of name using :

```
String name = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getString("name");
```

In java

```
{ 
    "result":
    {
        "name":   "ABC",
        "dob": "12-11-1958",
        "issue_date": "01-11-2011",
        "blood_group": "",
        "father/husband": "BCD",
        "address": "53/9 ASHOK NAGAR,Delhi 110018",
        "cov_details": {
            "LMV": "01-11-2011  DY.DIR.ZONAL OFFICE,NORTH WEST DISTRICT-II,ROHINI",
            "MCWG": "01-11-2011  DY.DIR.ZONAL OFFICE,NORTH WEST DISTRICT-II,ROHINI"
        },
        "validity": {
            "non-transport": "01-11-1958 to 31-10-1978",
            "transport": ""
        } 
    } 
}
```

It gives me:

> org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 6 exception.

Comment: You need to debug this. First check what is in "jsonObject", if it is correct then check for jsonObject.getJSONObject("result"), if this is also as expected then check jsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getString("name").
I hope this will help.

Comment: @charu Actually You are right, the problem is while debugging i get to know that it's sending me the Internal Server error, which actually doesn't happen to be case with the same request in REST POSTMAN client.

Comment: Moreover when i'm making this request
okhttp3.RequestBody body   =     okhttp3.RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"a_no\":\"123445566\",\"dob\":\"30-11-1992\",\"key\":\"abcd123\"}");

it's working fine, now what i'm trying to do is to pass the reference variable instead of static string, how can i do that.

Comment: Tidied up the code and some grammaticals.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you somehow did not load the right content. Here's a small program that consumes the input that you posted:

```
package org.json;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Scanner sc = new Scanner(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("in.json")); sc.hasNext(); ) {
      sb.append(sc.nextLine()).append("\n");
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    String name = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getString("name");
    System.out.println("name=" + name); 
    System.out.println("jsonObject=" + jsonObject); 
  }
}
```

The output is, as expected:

```
name=ABC
jsonObject={"result":{"cov_details":{"MCWG":"01-11-2011  DY.DIR.ZONAL OFFICE,NORTH WEST DISTRICT-II,ROHINI","LMV":"01-11-2011  DY.DIR.ZONAL OFFICE,NORTH WEST DISTRICT-II,ROHINI"},"address":"53/9 ASHOK NAGAR,Delhi 110018","issue_date":"01-11-2011","dob":"12-11-1958","name":"ABC","blood_group":"","validity":{"transport":"","non-transport":"01-11-1958 to 31-10-1978"},"father/husband":"BCD"}}
```

Therefore, I think you have problems in loading/initializing the object pointed by the `jsonObject` variable.

FTR, I am using the JSON library from https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java.

Comment: okhttp3.OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient();
public static void main(String[] args) {okhttp3.OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient(); MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
 okhttp3.RequestBody body = okhttp3.RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"a_no\":\"10830\",\"dob\":\"30-11-1992\",\"key\":\"abc\"}");
okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder().url("http://api.abc.com:8087/test")          .post(body).build(); okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

Comment: This is the program which i'm using which is providing me the correct value, Whereas while building the value with reference variable it's throwing error.

Comment: @Mavericks can you print the value of `jsonObject`, that is: `System.out.println(jsonObject)` ? This will make it easy to understand your problem

Comment: @Mavericks also, can you print what is the value of `response.body` ? In other words, you need to run your program but change the last lines to:  `okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute(); System.out.println(response.body().string());`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked after initializing the JSONObject and passing the 
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

Answer (score 0):

@Mavericks are you posting using retorfit? if yes then use compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0' for posting plain text.

Comment: Not precisely i'm using com.squareup.okhttp3 version 3.4

Comment: I think you have problem with slashes while making request please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568681/removing-in-json-object-string

Comment: thanks for your reply but this is not the case their is no any slash within my JSON as mentioned above in the sample JSON data.

Comment: print your reference variable it will be there its editor problem that's added extra slashes while you are creating JSON